# Auto snap of point features with lines

Tags: qgis, point, line, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I want to snap my point feature with Line features. So That I can perform join attribute by location to read attributed from points into lines. Is there any way I can do this task automated. Once points will be snapped/near to lines, I can do rest. Please respond if anyone has an idea.[image]

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 3 there is an algorithm 'snap geometries to layers'.  This can be found under processing > processing toolbox.

[image]

Take your point-layer as 'input layer'

Set your line-layer as 'Reference layer'